# What does 'stretches' mean in 'for long stretches of time'?

Tags: meaning

> I'll have to work really long hours and be away from my family for long **stretches** of time, but, on the flip side, I'll get the opportunity to travel around the world.

Sorry for confusing, just don’t understand the usage of the word ‘stretches’ in this sentence, does this means work over time? How could this be used in another example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "stretch", in itself, has no connection to the concept of working overtime, although in this case, I can see why you might think overtime was involved. A "stretch" of time is just an "interval" of time.

It is usually a *long* interval of time, e.g.: "The long stretch of time without fresh fruit or vegetables caused deficiency diseases like scurvy in many of the men."; "As a young man, he spent many long stretches of time alone in the wilderness." 
.... However, I think you could also say, "It was only 10 minutes. I didn't think you could get sunburned after such a short stretch in the sun." That sentence (*short* interval of time) sounds acceptable to me.